# Javascript setting html created element link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am working on creating a list of html elements using JavaScript.

Each element has an image and several lines of descriptive text, the code appears as such:

```
for (var i=0; i < json.length; i++){
        var section = document.createElement('section');
        var item = document.createElement('h1');
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        var datasheet = document.createElement('h3');

        item.textContent = "name: " + json[i][7];
        img.src="../cap/images/placeholder.png";
        datasheet.textContent= "../datasheet/test.pdf";


    section.appendChild(img);
    section.appendChild(item);
    section.appendChild(datasheet)

    body.append(section);
}
```

What tag can I use to turn the datasheet text into a link in html?
I have tried DOM tags such as : `'datasheet.link=', 'datasheet.href='` neither which work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

links are anchor tags `<a>` so you would use `document.createElement("a")`

If you want the link to be h3 styling just append the link to that element, or use css

```
var link = document.creaetElement("a");
datasheet.appendChild(link);
```

```js
var link = document.createElement("A");
link.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
link.textContent = "Link to stackoverflow";
document.body.appendChild(link);

var linkClone = link.cloneNode(true);
var datasheet = document.createElement("h3");

datasheet.appendChild(linkClone);
document.body.appendChild(datasheet);
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was going to be something simple. Thanks for the style info too!